# finding the size of a list consisting of lists

Tags: string, list, haskell

I've been trying to make a function in Haskell that has as an input a list that consists of lists and (it might sound pretty simple) I want this function to check if the input is a correct table with (m,n) dimensions. If it's not, it will return `(0,0)`. For example, if I input:

```
[[1,7,2,1],[2,2,7,8],[3,2,0,1]]
```

I'll get:

```
(3,4)
```

I need this function for rejecting invalid inputs in my program.

Comment: 'length' and 'map length' will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, to answer your actual question, don't use `(0, 0)` as the exceptional result.  Your function's type should be:

```
matrixDim :: [[a]] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
```

If the matrix is invalid, the result will be `Nothing`.  Now first check what the length of the first sublist is.  I'm assuming that a matrix must have at least one row and one column:

```
matrixDim [] = Nothing
```

Now you can use the fact that `Maybe` is a monad:

```
matrixDim (xs:xss) = do
    let w = length xs
    guard (w > 0)
    (w', h) <- matrixDim xss <|> return (w, 0)
    guard (w == w')
    return (w, h + 1)
```

And now let's get back to the actual problem at hand:  A list of lists is not what you want.  A much better data type for this kind of application is an array as defined in one of the `Data.Array.*` modules.  A more experimental alternative, where you get parallelization for free, is to use [repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa).

Comment: Maybe a bit advanced for the asker's level

Comment: It's odd how nobody noticed - this code is actually wrong. Try running it with `[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]` to get `Just (2, 1)`. That's because it is recursive and threats end of list and an error the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim :: [[a]] -> (Int, Int)
dim ls = let x = length ls
             ys = map length ls
         in case ys of
             h:t -> if all (==h) t then (x, h) else (0, 0)
             [] -> (0, 0)
```

Comment: I get an error when I run this one : parse error on input 'ys'

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/nnD0WI) it works. I have a feeling the spaces somehow turned into tabs, when you copied, or maybe some were lost..

Comment: @luqui, I consider the 6 lines of code to be self explanatory, but then, I see your point.

Comment: Those of us who understand this code just by looking at it are probably not the ones for whom it was intended :)